# Pandas query based on the list of columns and values

Tags: python, pandas, filter

Is there a way to automate the filtering process in pandas based on the columns and list of associated values the columns are supposed to take?

Please, see the example here:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

columns = ['sex']
values = ['Female']

df.query(@columns in @values)

columns2 = ['sex', 'smoker']
values2 = ['Male', 'Yes']
df.query(@columns2 in @values2)
```

Of course, this does not work but is there a way to do so?

The point is that the solution should be generalized as the length of the lists may differ.

Comment: I think you're looking for [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: `df.query("sex=='Female'")` and `df.query("sex=='Male' and smoker=='Yes'")`

Comment: Hi all, no I know about filtering "by hand" but I need one universal solution.

Answer (score 3):

- you need to conform with requirements of [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)
- this is straight forward with a **list comprehension** and **f-strings**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

columns = ['sex']
values = ['Female']

df.query(" and ".join([f"{c}=='{values[i]}'" for i,c in enumerate(columns)]))

columns2 = ['sex', 'smoker']
values2 = ['Male', 'Yes']
df.query(" and ".join([f"{c}=='{values2[i]}'" for i,c in enumerate(columns2)]))
```

Comment: I feel `zip` might be more clear here `" and ".join([f"{c}=='{v}'" for c, v in zip(columns2, values2)])` but otherwise I agree this is the way to go.

Comment: `join` can also take generators, so you can omit the extra `[]`, e.g.`" and ".join(f"{c}=='{values[i]}'" for i,c in enumerate(columns))`